# Statistical distribution of eigenvalues by Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, monte-carlo

i have a task of producing the statistical distributions of some eigenvalues (which belong to some certain matrices) through Monte Carlo simulations.
Could anyone give me some guidelines on how i should proceed with this task?
How do i apply Monte Carlo simulations?
And how can i use it to see the distributions of certain eigenvalues that i have?
Thank you

Comment: The Monte Carlo simulation should sample I guess the distribution of matrices you are interested in. But without knowing on which matrices you are interested the question remains a bit too generic I think...

Comment: @Thomas i have a set 192 unitairy matrices of size 2x2. i am looking to see if the eigenvalues of these matrices have a special distribution.

Comment: Why do you need Monte Carlo than? Isn't it enough to evaluate all of them?

Comment: @Thomas i actually don't understand why we use monte carlo. what you are saying is i don't need to run mo te carlo simulations sinxe the number of matrices is small? i just evaluate the distribution of the eigen values of these matrices directly and see if they belong to a special distribution?

Comment: Yes essentially that is what I was proposing.